# How to connect Superpad II P041 to pc

Tags: usb-drivers

I've a superpad II P041 and I would like to connect it to my pc. I would like to use Logcat for check exception thrown by my application.

The problem is that when I connect it with the USB cable, the pc doesn't recognise the tablet. I've already enabled the Debug USB.

What can I try to let the pc to communicate with the tablet? Maybe I need the drivers?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try the drivers.  [This post](http://www.apad.tv/apadforum/showthread.php?725-Superpad-III-Firmware-amp-Tools-Download) looks like it contains a link to a package with drivers.  Try installing the drivers from [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) if the above doesn't work and you can't find anything more official.